# Email notification for every question and comment in Chatter Questions?

Tags: chatter, customer-community

How can I have all Community users get an email notification for every question and comment in Chatter questions (actually on a Customer Community on Napili Template)?

Comment: Were you able to find a solution for this? We're in the same boat. Regards,
Kevin

Comment: Only a workaround, see: https://success.salesforce.com/0D53A00002g97GC